# Tkinter after() method only executes once

Tags: python, tkinter

After executing insertion() for the first time (i=0), it waits the 1000 ms but after it instantly inserts 'asd' into the other entry widgets.
How could I modify the program so that it waits 1000 ms each time before inserting into the other widgets?

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=600, width=540, bg='#F0F0F0')
canvas.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(bg='white', bd=0, width=1, justify='center')
entry2 = tk.Entry(bg='white', bd=0, width=1, justify='center')
entry3 = tk.Entry(bg='white', bd=0, width=1, justify='center')

canvas.create_window(30, 30, window=entry, height=50, width=50)
canvas.create_window(90, 30, window=entry2, height=50, width=50)
canvas.create_window(150, 30, window=entry3, height=50, width=50)

def insertion(entry_list, i):
    entry_list[i].after(1000, lambda: entry_list[i].insert(0, 'asd'))

entry_list = [entry, entry2, entry3]
for i in range(len(entry_list)):
    insertion(entry_list, i)
    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Instead of `.after(1000, ...`, you could use `.after(1000*i, ...` to schedule each insertion at different times in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways I would proceed here, one is as jasonharper mentioned in the comments, to increment the time over each iteration, but that just a hacky way around. I would say to get rid of the loop and then call the function each time using `after()`. Here is how I think it should be:

```
count = 0 # Initial index number
def insertion(count):
    entry_list[count].insert(0, 'asd')
    count += 1 # Increase the index number
    rep = root.after(1000,insertion,count) # Pass the new index number
    if count >= len(entry_list): # If count is more than number of items in 
    list, 
        root.after_cancel(rep) # Then stop repeating the function
root.after(1000,insertion,count) # Wait 1 second before inserting into first box

entry_list = [entry, entry2, entry3]
foo()
```

Now there will be 1 second delay each time the function is called.

If your wondering on how more you can shorten your code, then take a look here:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font

root = tk.Tk()
count = 0
def insertion(count):
    entry_list[count].insert(0, 'asd')
    count += 1 
    rep = root.after(1000,insertion,count)
    if count >= len(entry_list):
        root.after_cancel(rep)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=600, width=540, bg='#F0F0F0')
canvas.pack()

entry_list = []
x,y = 30,30 # x and y coordinates
TOTAL_ENTRY_NUMBER = 3
for i in range(TOTAL_ENTRY_NUMBER):
    entry_list.append(tk.Entry(bg='white', bd=0, width=1, justify='center'))
    canvas.create_window(x*(i+1)*2, y, window=entry_list[i], height=50, width=50) # i+1 because i starts from 0

root.after(1000,insertion,count) # Initial delay call to function
    
root.mainloop()
```